# Rust taking input in the same variable more than once behavior. Can anyone explain?

Tags: rust, std

So I tried to take input into the same variable called input with a loop. It behaves in a way that I do not know why.
Here is the snippet

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn main(){
    println!("Please Give Input: ");
    let mut input = String::new();
    loop{
        stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Error While Input");
        print!("{input}");
    }
}
```

on the first input it just prints the result. For Example: if I input `1`, it outputs `1`. but on the second input if I input `A` it is going to output: `1 A` and it goes on.

Thank you in Advance

I am trying to learn coding in rust. I was just experimenting with taking valid input from the command-line by looping through it multiple times, until the user inputs something valid. I was expecting only 1 value to stay in the variable but it has multiple values [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPTIH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line

`readline` appends to the buffer.  Move your `String::new` into the loop if you want just the last input

Comment: Better, call `clear()` at the beginning of the loop.